# TreeViewer: using Drag & Drop to reorder or reparent elements in a tree

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a TreeViewer of custom content. I'd like to be able to reorder it, much in the same was as the Outline View does currently when viewing Java Source.

Is there any reference material or documentation out there on how to achieve this?

Martin.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this:
http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Workbench-DND/drag_drop.html ?

Courtesy of http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.swt/msg40022.html